# Corona SDK is adding too much to the score

Tags: android, lua, coronasdk, collision

In my game the user scores a point when a balloon touches the top of the screen. It also loses a point when a balloon touches a bomb. The problem is when a balloon touches a bomb they disappear like they should but it takes way too much off the score anywhere from 5 to 30. This is my first game in Corona SDK so I'm still learning. Here is my the part of my code with the problem:

```
    local function onCollision(event)
        if (event.phase == "began") then
            event.object1:removeSelf()
            event.object2:removeSelf()

            score = score - 1
            scoreText.text = score
        end
    end

    local function addBomb()
        local startX = math.random(display.contentWidth * 0.1,     display.contentWidth * 0.9)

        local bomb = display.newImage("bomb.png", startX, -10)
        physics.addBody(bomb, "dynamic")
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", bomb)
        bomb:addEventListener("touch", bombTouched)
    end

    local function addBalloon()
        local startX = math.random(display.contentWidth * 0.1,  display.contentWidth * 0.9)

        local balloon = display.newImage("red_balloon.png", startX,   display.contentHeight + 50)
        physics.addBody(balloon, "dynamic")
        balloon.gravityScale = -1
        balloon.enterFrame = offscreen
        Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", balloon)
        Runtime:addEventListener("collision", onCollision)
    end
```

Please Help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A good way to prevent double events is to have a boolean which determines if the balloon has already been struck and is now 'inactive'.

You should do something like this:

- Give balloon the property `hasCollided` and set it to false

  - `balloon.hasCollided = false`
- Check the collision state in your collision event and change the state of your balloon

  ```
  if(!balloon.hasCollided) {
      ...collision logic
      balloon.hasCollided = true 
  }
  ```

Comment: Awesome it fixed my problem, Thanks!